# How to decide what will be the target android version?

Tags: android

I'm new in the android developing. 
I need to write some simple application - and i need to decide what will be the target version. 
I don't know how to decide this - because i want to support the most newer version with all the new abilities - but i also want to support the maximum devices ( there are few  devices that have old versions )

So, How to decide what will be the target version ?

Comment: There are actually two questions. The first, how do I select. 2nd, which version is optimal. The second question has been asked before several times on SA, but of course, the answer is different depending on when it was answered and what kind of app you are doing, and what target audience.

Comment: If you want to use functionality of the higher level API on a lower level device, I suggest use the [Android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) and there is an awsome free library [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) . With these libraries you can easily support maybe all Android version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Android Manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Ok, But when i define the project in the eclipse - what is the build sdk target that i need to choose ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Look at the array, i'd choose the 2.2 version of android, what coresponds to the API Level 8. For now i thinks that's the most comonly used version of Android.
And, btw, you can change the build sdk target anytime you wish so, just changing in it the Android Manifest.
Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to whatever is the last Android SDK version.
Quote from [Bruno Oliveira at Google IO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL4C6BCDE45E05F49E&feature=player_detailpage&v=amZM8oZBgfk#t=2137s):

> targetSdkVersion does not affect the minimum SDK level required to run your application. It should always be the latest version that you are aware of.

The only reason you could have to use a lower version would be to detect incompatibilities, but that is not a good reason because [Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) does this better.

---

**BUT** set your `android:minSdkVersion` to as low as your app will run on. That's the important one.

For instance, [my app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ichi2.anki) uses very new features, but I set `android:minSdkVersion` to `3` (which means Android 1.5). My code detects Android 1.5 devices, and uses less-shiny controls on them, but still runs correctly.

[Detection code sample](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/master/src/com/ichi2/charts/ChartBuilder.java#L103):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 4) {
        ActivityTransitionAnimation.slide(this, ActivityTransitionAnimation.UP);
    }
```

So, here is my suggestion:

- Set `android:minSdkVersion` to 3
- Everytime you discover an API is not present at that level, ponder whether the loss of potential users associated with increasing this number is worse than spending the time to implement a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I would say just start off with the lowest possible target and then as you encounter stuff that you can only do with a higher target you will have to change the target to the higher one. Using APIs that only work on for example 2.3 will show errors if your target is lower (because the APIs won't exist there).

Also you should consider the current state of the "fragmentation" to se what targets are actually being used out there. Looking at this chart (from October 5) maybe it could be worth just starting with 2.1 and se if it is high enough for all the things you want to do:

http://cdn.devilsworkshop.org/files/2011/09/android-OS-fragmentation-report.jpg

Comment: So, you suggest to choose api 1.6 ... as lower as possible ?

Comment: Well 1.6 if you want to support the few devices that still use it out there. 2.1 should be enough (looking at the chart).